# error to open db sqlite in android no such column locale

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-connection

I have this problem: I have an external sqlite file, and I put this on assets folder. In this database, I've created a table `android_metadata` with a column called `locale` and with one record `it_IT`.  When I start my application, it crashes immediately and logcat gives me this error:

```
03-28 21:12:23.193: E/SQLiteLog(2703): (1) no such column: locale
03-28 21:12:23.253: E/SQLiteDatabase(2703): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.provadatabase/databases/orari'.
03-28 21:12:23.253: E/SQLiteDatabase(2703): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.example.provadatabase/databases/orari' to 'en_US'.
```

Why this? I'm pretty sure `locale column` exists.

Comment: Your one record in locale should be `en_US`not `it_IT`.

Comment: also for en_US i've this problem

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Follow this way to set up `android_metadata`.

Comment: i've already follow this tutorial...